# Angular 2.0, how to detect route change on child component

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

How can I detect a route change on a child component?.
This is what I have tried, but I only see the app component trace the route change.
I want to be able to detect when the url change from e.g. #/meta/a/b/c to #/meta/a/b/c/d in the MetaDetailView component.

```
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/', name: 'Home', redirectTo: ['Meta']},
    { path: '/meta/...', name: 'Meta', component: MetaMainComponent, useAsDefault: true},
    ...other routes...,
  ])    
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private _router: Router) {
        _router.subscribe( (url) => console.log("app.url = " + url));
    }
}

@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/*other', name: 'Detail', component: MetaDetailViewComponent, useAsDefault: true},
])
export class MetaMainComponent {
    constructor(private _router: Router) {
        _router.subscribe( (url) => console.log("metamain.url = " + url));
        console.log("MetaMainComponent")
    }
}

export class MetaDetailViewComponent {
    constructor(private _router: Router) {
        _router.subscribe( (url) => console.log("metadetail.url = " + url));
        console.log("MetaDetailViewComponent")
    }
}
```

Thanks
Jesper

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a global service that subscribes to `router` and inject the service wherever you want to know about route changes. The service can expose changes by an `Observable` itself so interested components also can subscribe to get notified automatically.

Comment: That might work (will try it later today), but any idea why it doesn't work directly with Router ?

Comment: I think you only get a proper `Router` instance injected on components that take part in the routing. What you could try though is `_router.root.subscribe(...)`.

Comment: I was only able to get this working using an observable global service as suggested. Still don't understand why I cannot subscribe directly to the router on the child component.
I found this article on how to add an observable service .
https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-2-observable-data-services

Comment: You don't have `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` anywhere on your components (only in `bootstrap()`)?

Comment: yep, just double checked, it is only in the boot injection

`bootstrap(AppComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS
    , LoggerService
    , provide(LocationStrategy, { useClass: HashLocationStrategy })
    , RouteObserverService 
    ]);
`

Answer (score 14):

RC3+ solution:

```typescript
constructor(private router: Router) {
  router.events.subscribe(event => {
    if (event.constructor.name === 'NavigationStart') {
      console.log(event.url);
    }
  });
}
```

Alternatively, you can filter for the `NavigationStart` event using the [`filter`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/filter) pipe (RxJS 6+):

```js
constructor(private router: Router) {
  router.events.pipe(
    filter(event => event instanceof NavigationStart),
  ).subscribe((event: NavigationStart) => {
    console.log(event.url);
  });
}
```

Comment: ``this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
            if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
                console.log(event.url);
            }
        });`` 
don't forget to import NavigationStart from "angular/router"

Answer (score 3):

You have root access from any child router:

```
_router.root.subscribe(route => console.log('route', route));
```

Comment: and how to access _router variable

Comment: @RavinderPayal you have to inject to your component which have RouteConfig definition. You can inject it in constructor    constructor(private _router: Router) and after is accessible anywhere in your component via this._router

Comment: yeah i tried that and from that comment I mean to say Router variable is no longer subscriable

Comment: I tried to put this listener in a contructor for my AppComponent file (same ts file with my bootstrap and RouteConfig definition) but I am getting this error the second time I change the url address: Error: Uncaught (in promise): ObjectUnsubscribedError  Why do we need @RouteConfig([ ... ]) at all? I also tried to invoke a delegate service to put the _router.root.subscriber( ... listener and I also received the same error the second time I loaded a url

Comment: is this solution deprecated?